# How Do I include text from functions.php to index.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I do not know much about PHP. I am creating a settings page for my Wordpress theme. I want to change the text in index.php with the textboxes which is located in functions.php. I tried too many ways. I have assigned name, id, value in tag in index.php Just like aboutustitle in my functions.php source. But I didn't do it. How can I do that?

My code here

```
<?php
// create custom plugin settings menu
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_cool_plugin_create_menu');

function my_cool_plugin_create_menu() {

//create new top-level menu
add_menu_page('Yankı Tema Ayarlar', 'Tema Ayaları', 'administrator', __FILE__, 'my_cool_plugin_settings_page' , plugins_url('/images/icon.png', __FILE__) );

//call register settings function
add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_my_cool_plugin_settings' );
}


function register_my_cool_plugin_settings() {
//register our settings
register_setting( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group', 'aboutustitle' );
register_setting( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group', 'some_other_option' );
register_setting( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group', 'option_etc' );
}

function my_cool_plugin_settings_page() {
?>
<div class="wrap">
<h1>Tema Ayarları</h1>
    <p>Tema ayarlarınızı buradan düzenleyebilirsiniz</p>

<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <h2>Hakkımızda Kısmı</h2>
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Başlık</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="aboutustitle" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('aboutustitle') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Açıklama</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="some_other_option" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('some_other_option') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <?php submit_button(); ?>

</form>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can echo option in Wordpress using:

```
<p><?php echo get_option( 'option_name' ); ?></p>
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/

Answer (score 0):

dont know what exactly you meant here

but if you want to include something you can use this

```
<?php include 'functions.php';?>
```

for example this is my index php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
<?php include 'functions.php';
echo "I have a $color $car.";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

and in my functions php

```
<?php     
$color = "red"
$car = "BMW" ?>
```

so the output is

```
I have a red BMW
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I mean, there are functions.php and index.php. In functions.php there are a custom page. This custom page has one textbos within form. This forms action is option.php and also methods is post. This textbox integrated with some php codes as you see. In index.php there are `<p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>`. Now, When I type somethings in this textbox which is located in functions.php, and save settings, this p located in index.php, change to texbox writing.